# how to show the following expressions are identical?

Tags: trigonometry

$\frac{\sin \left(2k+2\right)\theta -\sin \left(2k\right)\theta }{2sin\theta }=cos\left(2k+1\right)\theta $

How do I show that the above is equal to each other?

The problem is part of an induction question and i am unable to show that LHS=RHS

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Comment: Use sum to product formula $$\sin a  - \sin b =2 \sin (\dfrac{a-b}{2}) \cos (\dfrac{a+b}{2})$$

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $$\sin \alpha - \sin \beta = 2 \cos \frac {\alpha + \beta}{2} \sin \frac {\alpha - \beta}{2} $$

Now seeking  $\alpha = (2k+2)\theta $ and $\beta = 2k\theta $ and simplifying, the result follows. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using -

$\sin A - \sin B = 2 \cos \frac{A+B}{2} \sin \frac{A-B}{2}$

So from above question we have -

$$= \frac{2 \cos \frac{(2k+2+2k)\theta}{2} \sin \frac{(2k+2-2k)\theta}{2}}{2\sin \theta}$$

$$= \frac{2 \cos (2k+1)\theta \sin \theta}{2\sin \theta}$$

$$=\cos (2k+1)\theta$$

Comment: Yes typo. Thnk u.

Comment: @Rohan I got to 2cos(2k+1)θsinθ2sinθ step but I am not sure how to simplify it to become cos(2k+1)θ

Comment: Eliminate $2\sin\theta$ in numerator and denominator.

Comment: You left with $\cos(2k+1)\theta$. Equals to right hand side.

Comment: @SonJerm Hope you know that $\sin$ and $\theta $ are connected. So don't cancel them separately.  Now coming to the point, you can see that the $2$ factor cancels out and then $\sin \theta $ factor also cancels out. Now what you get is $\cos (2k+1)\theta $.

Comment: Thank you very much @Rohan and Kanawaljit Singh I now understand how to show two identities are identical using the sum to product formula.

Comment: @Rohan Sorry but one more question relating to this topic, what would sin(2k) theta be identical to? I know that sin2 theta is 2sin theta cos theta

Comment: @SonJerm It is equal to $2\sin k\theta \cos k\theta $. Just check it for few values of $k $ if you want to get satisfied.

Comment: In this formula angle becomes half. So $\sin 2k\theta$ becomes $2\sin k\theta \cos k\theta$